# How to make the following sliders for a RGB program

Tags: java, rgb, sliders

I need make a program like a RGB selector, i have the sliders(sliderR, sliderG, sliderB) in my window, but i don't know how make that the sliders change the color instantly, the only i have is the following sliders code:

```
 sliderR.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
        int x = sliderR.getValue();
        int y = sliderG.getValue();
        area.setText("value = \n\n "+x);
        Color ColorR = new Color(x,y,0);
        area.setBackground(ColorR);         
    }
});
```

But, this code only varies for sliderR, the sliderG is static. How i can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you're not adding the listener to both sliders.

Try this:

```
ChangeListener listener = new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
        int x = sliderR.getValue();
        int y = sliderG.getValue();
        area.setText("value = \n\n "+x);
        Color ColorR = new Color(x,y,0);
        area.setBackground(ColorR);         
    }
});

sliderR.addChangeListener(listener);
sliderG.addChangeListener(listener);

// Add the listener to any other sliders you want to have this behavior.
```